# Find index of Linestring element at feature, when hovering - openlayers/GeoJson

Tags: openlayers, javascript, geojson, geometry, features

I have a Geo-JSON Linestring, this is drawn by 800 elements in OpenLayers 4.6.5.

I'am trying to use the map.forEachFeatureAtPixel, and print a pop-up when hovering for individual elements on the linestring. However, i have trouble identifying which element in the Linestring i'm CURRENTLY hovering over.

I can extract the whole array of 800 elements from my Linestring;

```
map.on('pointermove', function (evt2) {
var linefeature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt2.pixel, function 
(kfeature, layer) {
console.log(kfeature.N.geometry.A);
return kfeature;
}
```

I have tried to experiment with ***forEachSegment***, without any promising result:https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_geom_LineString-LineString.html

Same for the ***findIndex()***, i don't get any results.

How do I identify the elements in my Linestring?
Or suggestions for other ways to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would probably have get the point on the linestring corresponding to the pixel clicked, then convert each segment into a linestring to see it contains that point (using a for loop because `forEachSegment` doesn't pass an index):

```
var geometry = linefeature.getGeometry();
var point = geometry.getClosestPoint(getCoordinateFromPixel(evt2.pixel));
var coordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();
for (var element=0; element<coordinates.length-1; element++) {
  if (new.ol.geom.LineString([coordinates[element], coordinates[element+1]]).intersectsCoordinate(point){
     ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I will accept this as the answer. My solution ended up a bit easier. I still use the orEachFeatureAtPixel, and just do:

    'var coordinate = evt2.coordinate;'
    var mygeometry = kfeature.getGeometry();
    var point = mygeometry.getClosestPoint(coordinate);

Works like a charm for me :) No need for the for-loop with additional complexity (as is appreas to me.. :) ) But thanks for pointing a correct solution etc:)